# Using RestTemplate to send authorization certificates

Tags: java, spring, maven, curl

How can I use RestTemplate in Spring to perform a request like this?

```
curl --key test.key --cert test.pem --cacert testca.pem -k https://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send them as Headers i believe. There is class called as HttpEntity which can be used for sending the headers and request to the REST template. For more reference please find the below link

[Spring Basic Authentication](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/04/16/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring-3-1/)