# Using RestTemplate for making a Https call with certificates and keys in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, curl, resttemplate

I would like to make the following curl call using RestTemplate in my Spring Boot application:

```
curl -v --tlsv1.2 --cacert /etc/pki_service/ca/cacerts.pem --cert /etc/identity/client/certificates/client.pem -key /etc/identity/client/keys/client-key.pkcs8 https://server.com
```

I have gone through a similar question: [Using RestTemplate to send authorization certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646094/using-resttemplate-to-send-authorization-certificates) and [Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication), but not getting concrete steps to achieve exactly the same thing.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Spring Boot 3.1, you can configure the certificates and then apply them to the `RestTemplate` with a small amount of code.

Given your `curl` example above, you might configure an SSL bundle with the name `rest` in an `application.yaml` file like this:

```
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      pem:
        rest:
          keystore:
            certificate: "/etc/identity/client/certificates/client.pem"
            private-key: "/etc/identity/client/keys/client-key.pkcs8"
          truststore: 
            certificate: "/etc/pki_service/ca/cacerts.pem"
```

With this configuration, you can create a `RestTemplate` bean using the `SslBundle` named `rest`:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate sslRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, SslBundles sslBundles) {
        SslBundle sslBundle = sslBundles.getBundle("rest");
        return builder.rootUri("https://server.com").setSslBundle(sslBundle).build();
    }

}
```

See the latest [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.ssl) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Import your client.pem and client-key.pkcs8 into a java key store with `openssl` and java `keytool` like [this](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-import-an-existing-ssl-certificate-and-private-key#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20directly%20import,12%20file%20into%20your%20keystore.). It is possible to use a pem cert and a pkcs8 secret key directly but that is much more difficult to use them with java system properties.

Convert your pem style cacerts to a jks called cacerts.jks. I don't know what's in your cacerts.pem but doing this is similar to the previous step.

Allow the trusting of your server cacerts for server responses as follows:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks")
```

Add the inclusion of the client cert in RestTemplate calls: (assuming your created jks and password are "myKeystore.jks" & "changeit" respectively)

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",  "myKeystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
```

Force only TLSv1.2

```
System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocol", "TLSv1.2");
```

You may need to do the previous with a Java command line option `‑Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2"`